# 'Error: The class 'NavigatorObserver' can't be used as a mixin because it isn't a mixin class nor a mixin.'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I downloaded my code from FlutterFlow and I'm trying to run it. But it gives me this error

> Error: The class 'NavigatorObserver' can't be used as a mixin because it isn't a mixin class nor a mixin.

Here is a version of the code from FlutterFlow

```
class GoRouter extends ChangeNotifier with NavigatorObserver {
...
}
```

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: What is a NavigatorObserver class, Please add a code snippet of it. 
If you recently updated to latest Flutter and Dart, then there is a breaking change.
If you want to use a class as mixin then add mixin to the class
`mixin class NavigatorObserver{}`

https://dart.dev/resources/dart-3-migration#mixin

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the extends with implements:

```
class GoRouter implements ChangeNotifier with NavigatorObserver {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. But the fix I discovered is that I went to router.dart I think then I added a "mixin" keyword in the NavigorObserver class and it worked.

Comment: oh okay. Great!

Comment: @rtp_46 can you explain a bit, I'm haveing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

for me i just update goRouter to the last version